# Strange problems with virtual environment

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have problem with import:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import URLType
```

response is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy_utils'
```

I tried to import module from powershell. And it works! I tried to create virtual environment again. It doesn't solve the problem. What can I do? I have no idea

Comment: Did you install this module _into_ the virtual environment? You need to install while the virtual environment is active.

Comment: yes, virtual environment is activated and package is at venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages

Comment: i deleted cache files and it works